# How to debug a production Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have been assigned to find a bug in the dashboard of our (production) order management app. It shows wrong data. As I don't have that particular data locally, and can't get it soon, I will have to do it in the production app.

I have never worked with or in an app that is running live before and have no idea about best practices, no-gos, security precautions etc.

If someone could provide some clues to where to start reading (Software, Tools, Tutorials, ...) that would help me a lot. For some reason I only find info on how to prepare for and deploy Rails apps. But not about how to actually manage a running app (that has been deployed by someone else).

An example: As I needed to compare the stats with the real data, I wanted to run a console (`rails console --sandbox`) and have a look around, fire some queries. I tried:

- ssh into to the server which runs the app
- change into the rails app folder (`www/project-name/current`)
- run `rails console production`

But that last command gives me:

```
The program 'rails' can be found in the following packages:
* ruby-railties-3.2
* ruby-railties-4.0
```

So I guess I am not supposed to do that. 
How would I investigate such an error then? Querying the database directly seems dangerous.

Any tips? THX!

Comment: The fact that there is a current folder kind looks like a Capistrano deployment. Your idea should be correct (cd-ing into the current folder and open a console). Try `bin/rails c production`

Comment: Yeah it is a Capistrano deployment

Comment: Regarding your rails console problems: are you using rvm or another ruby switcher in prod? If yes, you need to select correct ruby before running console (so that it can find bundler, rails and other gems)

Comment: Ok, I am no expert on that, but on all the capistrano deployments I have worked with you need to use the rails binary to start a console :) when you are in the /project-name/current folder, type `bin/rails console production` instead of just `rails console production`

Comment: @ninigi thx, you are right. this brought me a step further. now the problem seems to be that there is no production database configured: `resolve_symbol_connection': 'production' database is not configured. Available: ["edge"] (ActiveRecord::AdapterNotSpecified)`

Comment: You have to setup a development environment (with separate RoR files and separate db). Do not make any changes at production version.

Comment: @ Sergio Tulentsev Alright, I have no idea what is set up there, but I will find out. gonna have a look at all Capistrano related files and read the docs there. This is probably what I was looking for, as it seems that production environments are very specific to the deployment method/technology?!

Comment: Capistrano can deploy your app to multiple environments, they do not have to be named "production" etc. You just have to find out which environment your app is running under

Comment: @GregDan: making changes is totally orthogonal to debugging. One very well can explore production db via console and try to find faulty data. When that's identified, a formal PR can be submitted.

Comment: @Flip The line of code you are looking for probably looks something like this: `set :stages, ["staging", "production"]`

Comment: @all:  Thx for the support, guys. Gonna dig into Capistrano!

Comment: Maybe Rails is not installed system wide, that's why you need to run `bundle exec rails c production`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As written by @ahmed-samir-shahin you need to use bundler to fetch the current ruby environment. When I have to debug production errors in my projects I typically use a command like

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rails console
```

I tend to use the `ENV` var instead of the `rails console <env>` notation.

As you are pointing out the error occurs on some dashboard. I assume that you are only reading data from your database there. If so I then use the code involved (most likely code from the controller action) for trying to debug the behaviour.

By running the code in the console you can narrow down to point where things are getting messed up. This is what I normally do when there is some kind of urgency involved and ONLY when you are just reading data from the database.

**BUT** you should try to get someone to make the data available in a staging environment where it is safe to play around with the data.

After figuring out why the problem occurs start setting up a test case on your local machine and fix the problem. :)

**Alternative**

Run the code / queries in the rails console. Store the results (copy and paste) and reuse the data to create a test case which you can then debug on your local machine.

**General advice - ask your boss for a strategy**

In general you should talk about this with your manager how to deal with these kind of situations. It is important to everyone in the team how to tackle problems in production systems. I think someone should be responsible for this kind of emergencies. Also some more experienced people in your company should help / assist you while you make your first steps in debugging production issues.

I think it's in the company's best interest to train you in that field. Imho your company has to provide some tools to make it easy to dive into the problem. Otherwise such debugging sessions take forever. Anyway no idea how your company is structured :)